# Как на JS в mozilla API удалить файл?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Всем хорошего настроения. Пишу макрос в мазиле, использую Imacros и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Не могу собрать скрипт для удаления файлов.

Пробовал сварганить такое, но оно не работает.

```
var path = "H:\\test.js";

var file = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/file/local;1", "nsILocalFile", "initWithPath")(path);
if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) file.remove(true);
```

Подскажите код для простого удаления указаного файла.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> file.isDirectory()
> ```

`!` пропустил.

> ```
> var path = "C:\\test.js";
> ```

А для этого вообще нужны админские права.

Comment: Этот код писал не я. Я его уже на просторах интернета нашел. Никак не могу найти как делается удаления. Нужно это сделать но только без activeX